# Autenticação com jwt

Tags: javascript, node.js, aplicação-web, jwt

Eu tenho uma função a para proteger a rota. Uso da seguinte maneira

```
const authMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.header('Authorization')?.replace('Bearer ', '')
    if(!token) return anauthorized(res)

    jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }

        console.log(decoded)
        next();
    })
}
```

Consigo pegar tudo direitinho. A função jwt.verify me traz um erro

```
JsonWebTokenError: invalid algorithm
```

Já tentei implementar diversas soluções, mas sem sucesso. O que eu poderia fazer?

Comment: O JWT possui, no cabeçalho, uma definição do algoritmo que foi utilizado ao ser assinado. Provavelmente você criou o _token_ com um algoritmo que não é suportado pela função `verify` que você está utilizando. Como você está criando o _token_?

Comment: Esse token vem a partir do login com o google, ele quem gera. Eu só faço enviar o mesmo no header do fetch.

Answer (score -1):

Esse código é de uma implementação que estou fazendo, substitui e vê se vc consegue!

```
function auth (req, res, next) {
    const authToken = req.headers['authorization'];

    if(authToken != undefined){
        const bearer = authToken.split(' ');
        var token = bearer[1];

        jwt.verify(token, chave, (err, data) => {
            if(err){
                res.status(401);
                res.json({err:"Token inválido"});
            }else{
                console.log(data)
                next();
            }
        })
    }else{
        res.status(401);
        res.json({err:"Token Inválido!"})
    }
    console.log(authToken);
}
```